# Is there a way to disable just copy and cut in a WebView for React Native app?

Tags: react-native

I would like to disable only the copy and cut options in a WebView with a contenteditable div. Users should still be able to select, lookup, paste and etc. How should I do this for a React Native app?

Answer (score -1):

If there are no other touchables(buttons etc) in your webview then you can do this. I was able to disable zooming, text selection and other pointer events on the React Native side, by wrapping WebView in a View and setting a few props:

```
<View pointerEvents="none">
  <WebView
   source={{ uri: webviewUrl }}
   scrollEnabled={false}
 />
</View>
```

Comment: Will it disable scrolling on a Webpage?

Comment: I want to still support selecting and pasting though.